# How to configure saxon on AWS lambda serverless for XSLT transformation

Tags: python, xslt, aws-lambda, saxon

I need to transform XML using XSLT on AWS lambda serverless, locally I'm using saxon and I don't know how to install or configure it on the AWS lambda.
I'm using Python 3.8

Comment: What are you using locally, Saxon Java or Saxon-C with its Python API? And obviously "transform XML using XSLT" is rather broad given that on AWS lambda you set up a function I think. Is it supposed to received a single XML document and transform it with a fixed XSLT into a single (XML?) result? Or what kind of request/response data is the function supposed to have?

Comment: For Saxon Java https://github.com/AtomGraph/XSLTTransform has example code.